# Php , my sql and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a table in my MySQL database called `studentname`.

I made an array in Javascript as `var array1=["john","sam","peter","kelvin"];`

I populated a `select` box with these array values.

If the table `studentname` contains names like "sam" and "peter", now I want to populate the select box with the values "john" and "kelvin" only, because "sam" and "peter" are already present in the database table.

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Stack Overflow is for specific answerable programming questions. The first thing you should try is pulling the names from the database into your PHP script via [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) Try this yourself, and if you get stuck, come back and ask something *specific* about the part that has tripped you up.

Comment: Fix the question title, please. Listing all the question's tags is _not_ acceptable as a summary of the question.

Comment: @meagar: and thanks for suggesting mysql_query to another beginner... nobody should be learning unsafe sql anymore, how long have we had http://php.net/PDO and parameterized queries now?

Comment: @Kris The `mysql_*` family of functions is only unsafe when used incorrectly but your point is valid. Honestly it's been a long time since I had to worry about how PHP was talking to the database; I blame ORMs :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a three-step process:

1. Modify your PHP script to connect to the database and retrieve the names from the 'studentname' table.
2. Output the names as a separate Javascript array.
3. When you create your select in Javascript, compare the values of array1 to the array created by your PHP code, and output only the elements that are unique.